# Golang htaccess configure without Nginx or Apache

Tags: .htaccess, go, webserver

I've created [web app](http://telegram-socks.tk/) and analyzed it with [Google site analyzer](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/).

In most cases I need to configure `htaccess` file. As I understand this file can be used only on Nginx or Apache server, but I don't want to use any of these.

I want to configure htaccess only with golang tools. Currently my app running on VPS server.

Comment: The question fails a critical part: *what* do you need `.htaccess` *for?* That is, it's a classic case of [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378): instead of explaining your problem, you fixate on one particular solution to it and ask about difficulties implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need .htaccess as it's only meant for Apache:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

If you use Apache, external services like Google Site Analyzer can't see .htaccess since it's not served by Apache. It's kept private.

Everything Apache can do with .htaccess, Go can do with [net/http](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http) or with a 3rd package like [Gorilla](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/) to help.

Comment: It is possible to support htaccess with non-Apache serers.  A golang implementation of the standard is here: https://github.com/abbot/go-http-auth.

Answer (score 2):

This project allows you to support the http auth standard with GO, zero apache code.

You can even use a password file created with the Apache htpasswd (bad) or htdigest (good) commands:

https://github.com/abbot/go-http-auth

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some constraints, then you may reference the following.

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "io/fs"
    "net/http"
    "path/filepath"
)

type TxtFileSystem struct {
    http.FileSystem
}

func (txtFS TxtFileSystem) Open(path string) (http.File, error) {
    if filepath.Ext(path) != ".txt" {
        return nil, &fs.PathError{Op: "open", Path: path, Err: fs.ErrNotExist}
    }
    return txtFS.FileSystem.Open(path)
}

func main() {
    m := mux.NewRouter()
    m.PathPrefix("/doc/").Handler(http.FileServer(TxtFileSystem{http.Dir("./doc")}))
}
```

That will only allow you to visit the file extension is `.txt`